# How to display Most Recently Read 10 Posts by a logged in user in wordpress

Tags: users, recent-posts

I'm wordpress newbie and working on a website where users can register and maintain their profile.

One of the main function of the logged in users is displaying their most RECENTLY READ 20 or 10 posts on their profile.

How can I do that without using a plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

At first you need to set a meta value when a post is visited using this way

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_readed_by', get_current_user_id() );
}
```

Then you can get the recent visited posts

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 10,
    'meta_key'         => 'post_readed_by',
    'meta_value'       => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
```

You can use the $posts_array variable this way

```
foreach ( $posts_array as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );

    the_title();
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail();
    } 
    the_content();

endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Hope you understand how to manipulate these

Comment: hello, then how can i display the posts with their featured images? please explain.

Comment: Updated the answer, now check

Comment: hi, can you please tell me where should i include all the above code? in the functions.php file or the page where i need to display the results?thank you again.

Comment: You can use this code to anywhere, don't know where you want to show the recent read posts, 

If you want to show on Custom page with shortcode, then design a shortcode for this, then using this function you can easily show that

Comment: hello, i used your code in my users profile page. but it display me nothing...

Comment: You can use this code to anywhere, don't know where you want to show the recent read posts, 

If you want to show on Custom page with shortcode, then design a shortcode for this, then using this function you can easily show that.

**If you still not sure how to do this, then I think you should hire an expert**

Comment: no what im telling you is i'm getting nothing, even a error message when i put your code.. so thats why im struggling to find the issue..thanks